# git: unable to cherry-pick a range

Tags: git

I am using `git cherry-pick hashA..hashB` command for picking changes. It used to work, but now I'm getting the following error:

```
Updating b18011096..d8641c4df
...
error: a cherry-pick or revert is already in progress
```

But there is none and `git status` shows a clean tree.

Under what situation would this happen?

Comment: Have you ever tried `git cherry-pick --abort`?

Answer (score 1):

You're already in the middle of a cherry-pick (or revert).<sup>1</sup>  You must finish it before you start a new series of cherry-picks.  Either finish the current one, or abort it entirely (note that this resets your index and work-tree!).

If you have a modern Git, `git status` will tell you whenever you are in the middle of an unfinished cherry-pick or revert.

---

<sup>1</sup>These two are secretly implemented by a single engine inside Git, called the *sequencer*.  In modern Git the sequencer also handles interactive rebase, since rebase is effectively a series of cherry-pick operations followed by one `git reset`.

Comment: that's. the thing.  I wasn't in a cherry-pick at all. I tried with a clean tree from `git clone` and the same happens. Maybe I should upgrade my git client....